# PHP Decrease a Few Seconds of the "datetime"

Tags: php

In my code, I get the current time and date value of the server following this organization parameter:

```
Y-m-d H:i:s        Ex: 2018-09-01 22:35:18
```

I would like to remove 30 seconds of the time to use in the `if` comparison.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what your question is about. Please show your code, any erros and expected results. The code may be very helpful in understanding the issue.

Comment: @LeoTahk That won't compare anything so it will always be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)* function to add or subtract time.

If you want to subtract 30 seconds to current timestamp:

```
$thirtySecondsAgo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-30seconds'));
```

If reference date is not NOW:

```
$date = "2018-08-15 22:51:47";
$dateThirtySecondsAgo = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date . '-30seconds'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for example current date minus 30 seconds:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-30 second'));
```